# AppEngine position of row in result set

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling, app-engine-ndb

I'm working on an App with a leader board, the leader board is updated constantly. When I display the leader board, I do so by applying sort order over multiple columns.

What I want to do though, is with the sorting in place, work out where a user(key) is ranked in the result set.

The leader board looks like this:

```
userKey->Key Property
todaysXScore->Int
TotalXScore->Int
todaysYScore->Int
TotalYScore->Int
todaysZScore->Int
TotalZScore->Int
```

A solution I've thought of is to just simply get the result set and then search for the user I'm looking for and take the position as the Rank, but that seems inefficient, although I have not timed this yet.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14494606/535661

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Engine ndb: find the position of an order query list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493479/google-app-engine-ndb-find-the-position-of-an-order-query-list)