# Google App Engine ndb: find the position of an order query list

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling

On Google App Engine's ndb, I used the following to retrieve all entities and sort them according to their grade:

```
ranks = Member.query().order(-Member.grade)
```

Then I would like to know the position of a specific member:

```
i = 0
for rank in ranks:
    if rank.account == 'abc'
        position = i
        break
    i += 1
```

My question: is there an equivalent ndb operation to find the position of a specific entity? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it could be done in two steps

1. Retrieve the entry whose account is 'abc'

   target = Member.query(Member.account=='abc').get()
2. Query for entries with higher grade

   n =  Member.query(Member.grade>target.grade).count()

Then you get target's rank as n+1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to find the rank of a member. Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-ranklist/ which will enable you to find the rank, with a query, without needing to loop through all the scores.